# How to list all pages of a github organization

Tags: github-pages

I am new to a `GitHub Organization`, and some of the document/guides is Not on `README.md`/`Wiki`/`docs`, but on `GitHub Pages`. So

Is there any way to list all available `GitHub Pages` on this `GitHub Organization`?

I've tried `gh`/`git` CLI, and GitHub GUI, not none of them could achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user site or an organisation site would be a repository named `<username>.github.io` or `<organization>.github.io`, so that is easy enough to check.

But a project site would be any repository with a '`has_pages`' attribute set to `true`.

That means you can [list org repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organization-repositories), focusing on that attribute, to filter out the ones which does have pages

```
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /orgs/ORG/repos --jq '.[].has_pages'
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @VonC's answer, this command in bash will show you only the repositories in which have github pages:

```bash
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" orgs/ORG/repos --jq '.[] | {name: .name, has_pages}' --paginate | grep true
```

sample output:

```
{"has_pages":true,"name":"repo-with-gh-pages"}
```

Comment: Nicely done. Upvoted.